# what is the right preposition "bad points of/about"

Tags: grammar, prepositions

**What is the right preposition to use here?**

- One of bad points **of/about** having children is being worry all the time.
- One of the main bad points **of/about** my hometown is pollution.

Comment: Both prepositions are fine. You could also use ***to***, and perhaps others. Note that "one of the bad points/things" might sound a bit "childish" to many native speakers, who might well prefer "one of the ***disadvantages***" (where ***to*** would be far more common that ***about***).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally feel that you can use both of them interchangeably here and it would still be grammatically correct. However, to a native English speaker, it might sound more natural to say '**one of the bad things about/of**' instead of 'points'.